# Why isn't my rewrite rule for add_rewrite_rule not working as expected?

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have a post type 'destinations' which should work without the custom post type slug, but it should be hierarchical. So a page like this can exist: `/madagascar/grouptrip/information`
I wanted to creat a rewrite rule to match the main parents (madagascar and uganda) and match all child pages hierarchical. So I had a look at the rewrite rule used for pages:

`(.?.+?)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$`

and added my main parents in front of it:

`add_rewrite_rule('(madagascar|uganda)/(.?.+?)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$', 'index.php?destination=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&page=$matches[4]', 'top');`

This is working for my example url `/madagascar/grouptrip/information` However if I add a pagenumber at the end `/madagascar/grouptrip/information/2` it isn't working. The exact same structure is matched by the regex for pages which I copied. Only when i remove the colon from the regex the rewrite rule is working and I don't understand why?

**So to sum it up:**

`(.?.+?)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$`

is working for a structure like:

`/pagename/subpage/2`

But:

`(madagascar|uganda)/(.?.+?)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$`

is not working for a structure like:

`/madagascar/subpage/2`

and:

`(madagascar|uganda)/(.?.+?)?(/([0-9]+))?/?$`

is working. Why isn't the copied regex working?

Answer (score 0):

so the problem with the colon is that it has no special meaning so your regex is looking to match `:/` literally - that would work for a string with a structure like:

`/madagascar/subpage:/2`

you would get a full match and 4 groups:

```
array 
(
    [0] => 'madagascar/subpage:/2'
    [1] => 'madagascar'
    [2] => 'subpage'
    [3] => ':/2'
    [4] => '2'
)
```

but since the colon is not in your tested string, all you get is a full match and two groups (only parts `(madagascar|uganda)`and `(.?.+?)?` tested positive)

```
array
(
    [0] => 'madagascar/subpage/2'
    [1] => 'madagascar'
    [2] => 'subpage/2'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this does not explain why the same regex `(.?.+?)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$` is working for this structure: `/pagename/subpage/2`